# Prevent hard reset from deleting registry changes under WIN7?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, registry

I'm editing the Windows registry through my software, which for example replaces the Shell (Kiosk app).

Now I have just noticed that under Win7 if a hard-reset occurs (reset button, or 4 second power button) all the registry changes are lost.

Under WinXP however it works fine, even after a hard reset the changes I made are still there.

Do I have to do anything special after editing the registry under Win7 or is this even a built-in Win7 security feature maybe ?

To me it looks like that the registry changes aren't finalized and just saved in the memory until a soft-reset occurs, could this be true ? If so, can I force a save somehow ?

Comment: Are you running 32 bit software on 64 Windows ? Maybe registry virtualisation is involved. Where are those key you set reset ?

Comment: In addition to @ixe013's question, is your app running under an Administrator account when it makes the registry changes?

Comment: This was infact true, I did try it on a 64bit Win7, although I just tried it on a 32bit machine, the result is the same. Also, yes I am using an Administrator account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [`RegFlushKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724867.aspx) function.

> The `RegFlushKey` function returns only when all the data for the hive that contains the specified key has been written to the registry store on disk.
>
> The `RegFlushKey` function writes out the data for other keys in the hive that have been modified since the last lazy flush or system start.

Comment: This looks indeed like what I want. I tried to google for an example on how to use it, but nothing really came up, could you please give me an example on how to use it ?

Comment: @user990767: How are you editing the registry?  Are you using WinApi functions (so you have an `HKEY`) or something built into Delphi?

Comment: Ben: +1. @user, if you're using Delphi's `TRegistry`, set the `TRegistry.LazyWrite` to false before writing your key. It does the `RegFlushKey` for you before closing the key.

Comment: What's to demonstrate, User? When you're finished writing your changes to the registry, you call `RegFlushKey`. Pass it the same registry key you used for all your other operations. (If you're using `TRegistry`, then that's the `CurrentKey` property.)

Comment: A little more googling and I found this: Registry.LazyWrite :=false;  now it works flawlessy, without your answer I would not have found this, thank you ! // Edit: Looks like I should refresh more often, exact same answer with LazyWrite was posted in the comments i see now, thanks to everyone!

Comment: @user990767: Ah, I thought you knew how to call winapi functions because your question had that tag.  But now I see someone else added it.  Anyway, Ken gave you the Delphi-friendly answer in a comment above.